# Numpy: how to reshape multiple rows and columns from one row in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of data with one row and I want to reshape it into multiple rows and 10 columns (kind of multiple dimensional). Here is an example of my data:
VALUES: [     0      0      0 ...   5740 -11760   8510]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


data = np.memmap("F:\data.pcm", dtype='h', mode='r')
print("VALUES:", data)
# conv = np.array(data, 8)
# print(conv)
pylab.plot(data)
pylab.show()
np.save("data_signal.npy", data)
l = np.load("data_signal.npy")
print(l)
new_data = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape([],3))
print(new_data)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `l.reshape`?

Comment: This example is not reproducible - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Indeed I had inserted .reshape on this line and then this one. Unfortunately, nothing worked. And when I try the `l.rehape` I get this error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1584000 into shape (5,208000)` and I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. @Joe Ferndz, It what I wanted.

Comment: Well reshaping 1584000 into 5,208000 isn't possible because to reshape it has to be an integer multiple. For example, you can reshape say a `arr.shape = (1,9)` array into `(3,3)` but you won't be able to do `(2,...)`. So the question is what are your arrays dimensions?

Comment: @astrochun I have a list type of one dimension. The `arr.shape = (1,9)` works well in my code by writing `l.shape = (-1,5)`. So now I have an array of 5 columns and multiple rows. Thanks